# Deploying asp.net mvc iis6.0 how to change route TO include .aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

This is my routing tables where do I put the various '.aspx' registrations?

```
//Turns off the unnecessary file exists check
this._Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

//Ignore text, html, xml files.
this._Routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.txt");
this._Routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.htm");
this._Routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
this._Routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.xml");

//Ignore axd files such as assest, image, sitemap etc
this._Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

//Ignore the assets directory which contains images, js, css & html
this._Routes.IgnoreRoute("Assets/{*pathInfo}");

//Ignore the error directory which contains error pages
this._Routes.IgnoreRoute("ErrorPages/{*pathInfo}");

//Exclude favicon (google toolbar request gif file as fav icon)
this._Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.([iI][cC][oO]|[gG][iI][fF])(/.*)?" });

//Photo routes
this._Routes.MapRoute("PhotoAssets", "Photos/Photo/{photoId}/Size/{photoSizeClassificationId}", MVC.Photo.Photo(0, null));

//Handles department profile routes 
this._Routes.MapRoute("WorkerProfileLeader", "Department/{departmentId}/Worker/Profile/Leader/List/{viewType}", MVC.WorkerProfile.List(PersonType.Leader, "", DisplayViewType.SummaryThumbnailList));
this._Routes.MapRoute("WorkerProfile", "Department/{departmentId}/Worker/Profile/{personType}/List/{viewType}", MVC.WorkerProfile.List(PersonType.Pleb, "", DisplayViewType.ThumbnailGrid));
this._Routes.MapRoute("WorkerProfilePerson", "Department/{departmentId}/Worker/Profile/{personType}/Detail/{personId}", MVC.WorkerProfile.Detail(PersonType.Pleb, "", ""));

//Default route mapping
this._Routes.MapRoute("Start", "Default.aspx", MVC.Home.Index());
this._Routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", MVC.Home.Index());
```

Cheers
Anthony

Comment: do you not want the wildcard setup? as described by phil haack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure the first part or the URL ends with **.aspx** like:

```
this._Routes.MapRoute("WorkerProfileLeader", "Department.aspx/{departmentId}/Worker/Profile/Leader/List/{viewType}", ...
this._Routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}.aspx/{action}", MVC.Home.Index());
```

Comment: Cheers thats what I wanted to know

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it in fact doesn't matter *where* in the URL the .aspx is as long as it's somewhere in there and is the first thing that appears to be a file extension. In fact, one trick I've seen is to put the .aspx in the folder name containing the application! In other words, the application name itself would be "myapp.aspx" even though that's just a folder.

As long as .aspx appears as the first file extension in the path IIS will use that file extension to handle the request.